# Codeigniter manipulate DOM from view?

Tags: php, codeigniter, jquery

In order to best organize JavaScript AJAX handlers in a web app, I'm taking the approach of using an AJAX controller to process the AJAX requests.  Simple enough.

The second half of this decision is the result of the AJAX request, and specifically how, where, and if the JSON/data returned is added to DOM elements.  Is it a good (or at least non-foolish idea) to put the JavaScript DOM manipulation logic within the view?

Comment: I would suggest that if you want to do something to manipulate how the page is shown then its the view you want to update .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I normally handle AJAX and all JavaScript execution within a static .js file. This way, I can handle a request whether it's ajax or not, and I can keep my logic in one place. So, I might have the following setup:

```
// application/controllers/Mycontroller.php
class Mycontroller extends CI_Controller {
    function index()
    {
        $content['text'] = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...";
        $data['content'] = $this->load->view('embeds/home_page', $content, TRUE);
        $this->load->view('public_template', $data);
    }
}

// embeds/home_page.php
<div id="container">
    <h1>Home Page</h1>
    <p><?php echo $text; ?></p>
    <a href="/my_other_controller/method.php">Change Content</a>
</div>

// public_template.php
<html>
<head>
  <title>Home Page</title>
  <script src="/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="/myscript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <?php echo $content; ?>
</body>
</html>

// myscript.js
$(function(){
    $("#container a").live("click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr("href"),
            success: function(data) {
                $("#container p").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});

// my_other_controller.php
class My_other_controller extends CI_Controller {
    function method(){
        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']=="XMLHttpRequest") {
            // is an ajax request
            echo "This is new content for the page.";
        } else {
            // is not an ajax request, render whole page
            $content['text'] = "This is new content for the page.";
            $data['content'] = $this->load->view('embeds/home_page', $content, TRUE);
            $this->load->view('public_template', $data);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm considering using this approach, but am concerned about the amount of content in the myscript.js file.  There could potentially be 40 or more of these functions, and then it would require its own organizing.

Comment: That's not uncommon for a js file. But you could always separate files and only load those needed on specific pages.